# Rounding an array to values given in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

Say I have an array:

```
values = np.array([1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,2.1,8.4])
```

I want to round these values to members of an arbitrary array, say:

```
rounds = np.array([1.,3.5,5.1,6.7,9.2])
```

ideally returning an array of rounded numbers and an array of the residues:

```
rounded = np.array([1.,1.,3.5,5.1,1.,9.2])
residues = np.array([-0.1,-1.2,0.2,0.7,-1.1,0.6])
```

Is there a good pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Can you explain what is the rounds array?

Comment: An array of numbers containing values that I want the elements of the first array to be rounded to.

Comment: what I see here is a substract between the two array. What do you mean by round values from one aarray to another ?

Comment: For example `2.1` in `values` is closest to `1.` in `rounds`, therefore the corresponding element in `rounded` is `1.`. It is not a subtraction, the arrays have different lengths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is this:

```
>>> x = np.subtract.outer(values, rounds)
>>> y = np.argmin(abs(x), axis=1)
```

And then `rounded` and `residues` are, respectively:

```
>>> rounds[y]
array([ 1. ,  1. ,  3.5,  5.1,  1. ,  9.2])

>>> rounds[y] - values
array([-0.1, -1.2,  0.2,  0.7, -1.1,  0.8])
```

Essentially `x` is a 2D array of every value in `values` minus every value in `rounds`. `y` is a 1D array of the index of the minimum absolute value of each row of `x`. This `y` is then used to index `rounds`.

I should caveat this answer by noting that if `len(values) * len(rounds)` is big (e.g. starting to exceed `10e8`), memory usage may start to become of concern. In this case, you could consider building up `y` iteratively instead to avoid having to allocate a large block of memory to `x`.

Comment: Might take some extra memory for bigger arrays, but very concise.

Answer (score 2):

As the items in `rounds` array are sorted(or if not sort them) we can do this is `O(n logn)` time using [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
from functools import partial

def closest(rounds, x):
   ind = np.searchsorted(rounds, x, side='right')
   length = len(rounds)
   if ind in (0, length) :
      return rounds[ind]
   else:
      left, right = rounds[ind-1], rounds[ind]
      val = min((left, right), key=lambda y:abs(x-y))
      return val

f = partial(closest, rounds)
rounded = np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, values[:,None])[:,0]
residues = rounded - values
print repr(rounded)
print repr(residues)
```

**Output:**

```
array([ 1. ,  1. ,  3.5,  5.1,  1. ,  9.2])
array([-0.1, -1.2,  0.2,  0.7, -1.1,  0.8])
```

Answer (score 2):

The same time complexity as the answer by Ashwini Chaudhary, but fully vectorized:

```
def round_to(rounds, values):
    # The main speed is in this line
    I = np.searchsorted(rounds, values)

    # Pad so that we can index easier
    rounds_p = np.pad(rounds, 1, mode='edge')

    # We have to decide between I and I+1
    rounded = np.vstack([rounds_p[I], rounds_p[I+1]])
    residues = rounded - values
    J = np.argmin(np.abs(residues), axis=0)

    K = np.arange(len(values))
    return rounded[J,K], residues[J,K]
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the closest number of x in rounds:

```
def findClosest(x,rounds):
    return rounds[np.argmin(np.absolute(rounds-x))]
```

Loop over all values:

```
rounded = [findClosest(x,rounds) for x in values]
residues = values - rounded
```

This is a straightforward method, but you can be more efficient using that your rounds array is ordered.

```
def findClosest(x,rounds):
    for n in range(len(rounds)):
        if x > rounds[n]:
            if n == 0:
                return rounds[n]
            elif rounds[n]-x > x-rounds[n-1]:
                return rounds[n-1]
            else:
                return rounds[n]  

        return rounds[-1]
```

This might be, but not necessarily is faster than the argmin approach because you lose time with the python for loop, but you don't have to check along the whole rounds array.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is already great. This one may seem convoluted to those that aren't necessarily used to more complex list-comprehensions, but otherwise it's actually quite clear (IMO) if you're familiar with it.

(*Interestingly enough*, this happens to run faster than the selected answer. Why would the numPy version be slower than this? Hmm... )

```
values = np.array([1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,2.1,8.4])
rounds = np.array([1.,3.5,5.1,6.7,9.2])

rounded, residues = zip(*[
    [
        (rounds[cIndex]),
        (dists[cIndex])
    ]
    for v in values
    for dists in [[r-v for r in rounds]]
    for absDists in [[abs(d) for d in dists]]
    for cIndex in [absDists.index(min(absDists))]
])

print np.array(rounded)
print np.array(residues)
```